# How to echo values in forms

Tags: php, forms

I am echo values by the codes below. but i want to create for each values form for saving to database.
How can i insert form inside echo ?

I am beginer in php and i want form like this and it must replace with all echo values.

```
----FORM----
Thumbnail url : 
url : 
description: 
submit Button 
----FORM----
```

this is the code

```
 foreach($posts as $post){
 if ($post){
        echo $post->thumbnail . "<br />";
        echo $post->url . "<br />";
        echo $post->description . "<br />";     
        }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the object $posts?

Comment: Could you please post the HTML so we can see exactly what is being posted?

Comment: I create post with api , i just need how to insert form to php eco

Comment: Please show how the data is being sent to PHP and how you are creating the object $posts

Answer (score 0):

I solved how to add.

```
foreach($posts as $post){
 if ($post){
        echo '<input id="title" class="form-control" type="text" name="title" value="'.htmlspecialchars($post->thumbnail).'">';
        echo '<input id="teaser" class="form-control" type="text" name="teaser" value="'.htmlspecialchars($post->Url).'">';
        echo '<input id="text" class="form-control" type="text" name="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($post->description).'">';
        echo '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">add</button>';

        }
}
```

this works fine... My second question is how i can add the code below codes to inside echo in a same way ?
i tried to add same way but (if isset line ) gives error

```
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="news" />
<input type="hidden" name="edit_news_submit" value="true" />
<?php if(isset($edit_news['id'])): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $edit_news['id']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have solved this too...ITS WORKING NOW. below is the code and it working good. If you know PHP can you tell me did i do in correct way. because i just tried and found. i dont know any php.


   echo '<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="news" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="edit_news_submit" value="true" />';
   if(isset($edit_news['id'])): 
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.htmlspecialchars($edit_news['id']).'" />';
   endif;